# How to Make Buttons Stay the Same Link Color?

Tags: html, css, colors, hyperlink

By clicking on the **index submit button** the color of "New Value" changes & stays gray, which is the color of visited links whereas the **_form submit button** stays the same color white regardless.

I want the buttons stay white whereas all other links should change colors according to if it is visited or not.

Can you please help me?

**index.html.erb**

```html
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= link_to 'New Value', new_value_path, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
```

**_form.html.erb**

```html
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
```

**values.css.scss**

```html
// Place all the styles related to the Values controller here.
// They will automatically be included in application.css.
// You can use Sass (SCSS) here: http://sass-lang.com/

.category {
  width: 130px
}

td {
  padding-top: .7em;
  padding-bottom: .7em;
  padding-left: .7em;
  padding-right: .7em;
}

.btn {
  background: #3498db;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  -webkit-border-radius: 28;
  -moz-border-radius: 28;
  border-radius: 28px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #3cb0fd;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:active{
  color:red;
}
```

**scaffolds.css.scss**

```html
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
  font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 18px;
}

p, ol, ul, td {
  font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 18px;
}

pre {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

a {
  color: #000;
  &:visited {
    color: #666;
  }
  &:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
  }
}

div {
  &.field, &.actions {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}

#notice {
  color: green;
}

.field_with_errors {
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: red;
  display: table;
}

#error_explanation {
  width: 450px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  h2 {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 15px;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: -7px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    background-color: #c00;
    color: #fff;
  }
  ul li {
    font-size: 12px;
    list-style: square;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In index page you are using a `link_to` item and that will give you a behavior of `<a>`.
And you given CSS for `a` as

```
a {
  color: #000;
  &:visited {
    color: #666;
  }
  &:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
  }
}
```

So the color changes as per the css you have given.

And in `_form` page you have used `input type` with `submit` button and that is linked with class `btn` css. So the submit button is consuming that css.